# Need help in terraforming the code (azure keyvault )with the specific naming conventions

Tags: azure, terraform

I have below terraform code, need help in identifying which value to be given for a specific solution_settings variable and the code should work as I am new to Terraform.

Need help in identifying the solution name in solution_setting variable

Answer (score 0):

> I tried the code (azure key vault)with the specific naming conventions using **solution settings** variables I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

The error messages indicate two main issues:

- You are prompted for the value of `var.solution_settings` and `var.tags`, but they are not set, leading to an error.
- The use of variables in certain contexts where they are not allowed.

These variables need to be properly defined and passed to Terraform. They are not given default values in your `variables.tf` file, so they must be provided either via command line, a Terraform.tfvars file

Make sure that variables are used in allowed contexts. Terraform does not permit variables in certain places such as module source fields or provider configuration.

I tried a demo configuration to pass the **solution settings** using **variables** and declaring them using **terraform.tfvars** as I could not demonistrate the complete configuration youre looking for.

**My terraform Configuration:**

**Main.tf:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
}

data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = var.solution_settings["resource_group_name"]
  location = var.location
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "edemovk-vnet"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "demovk-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "example" {
  name                = "demovk-law"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  sku                 = "PerGB2018"
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault" "example" {
  name                     = var.solution_settings["key_vault_name"]
  location                 = var.location
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  tenant_id                = var.solution_settings["azure_tenant_id"]
  sku_name                 = "standard"
  tags                     = var.tags
  soft_delete_retention_days = 7
  purge_protection_enabled = true
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "example" {
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
  tenant_id    = var.solution_settings["azure_tenant_id"]
  object_id    = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id

  secret_permissions = [
    "Get",
    "List",
    "Set",
    "Delete",
    "Recover"
  ]

  key_permissions = []

  certificate_permissions = []
}

resource "azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting" "example" {
  name                       = "${azurerm_key_vault.example.name}-log"
  target_resource_id         = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
  log_analytics_workspace_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.example.id

  enabled_log {
    category = "AuditEvent"

  }

  metric {
    category = "AllMetrics"
    enabled  = true
  }
}

resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "example" {
  name                = "${azurerm_key_vault.example.name}-pe"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  subnet_id           = azurerm_subnet.example.id

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "${azurerm_key_vault.example.name}-psc"
    is_manual_connection           = false
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
    subresource_names              = ["vault"]
  }
}
```

**variable.tf:**

```
variable "solution_settings" {
  type = map(string)
  description = "Settings for the solution"
}

variable "tags" {
  type = map(string)
  description = "Tags for the resources"
}

variable "location" {
  description = "Azure region for the resources"
  type        = string
  default     = "West Europe"
}
```

**terraform.tfvars:**

```
solution_settings = {
  resource_group_name = "demorg-vk"
  key_vault_name      = "vksbKeyVault"
  azure_tenant_id     = "your tenent ID"
}

tags = {
  Environment = "Dev"
  Project     = "MyProject"
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]